# How do I install libcamera-apps on Ubuntu Server 22.04 (on rpi4 2gb)?

Tags: 22.04, raspberrypi, libcamera

I have Ubuntu Server 22.04 installed from the official Ubuntu image for rpi.

I'd like to use commands such as:

```
cam -l
or
libcamera-vid -t 0 --inline --listen --width 1920 --height 1080 --framerate 30 --rotation 180 --codec h264 -n -o tcp://0.0.0.0:8554
```

I understand that the only way to get libcamera-apps is to compile them from source. I came to this conclusion following these links:

[raspberry pi forum](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=339606)

[github](https://github.com/raspberrypi/rpicam-apps?tab=readme-ov-file)

[Official Rpi document](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/camera_software.html#building-libcamera-and-rpicam-apps)

I am having a lot of trouble following the instructions for building rpicam-apps.

1. It is really unclear if these instructions are valid for Ubuntu, as opposed to RPi-OS.
2. It is unclear if I should use the version of libcamera in Ubuntu repository, or build it from source from (which branch?) in github.
3. meson is out of date in Ubuntu 22.04 repository.  I have to install it, and there is a lot of confusion over whether or not to use sudo.

I do not understand the consequences of using sudo to install meson.  Some people recommend it, and some do not!  I do know that the choice affects the final installation step.

I have already made numerous attempts at compiling rpicam-apps, but cam and libcamera-vid do not work and cam gives a segmentation fault.

It is difficult to get help because rpi experts think this is a Ubuntu problem and Ubuntu experts think it is a Raspberry Pi problem.